# Inverse trigonometric equations $\arcsin \left(1-x\right)+\arccos \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi }{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Consider we have been given that

> $$\arcsin \left(1-x\right)+\arccos \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi
> }{2}$$

How would you solve this trigonometric equation? In other words, Is there any difference between

> $$\sin \left(1-x\right)+\cos \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi }{2}$$

Regards!

Comment: It is as if you were asking for the difference between $x^2+e^x=2$ and $\tan\sqrt x=x+5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should draw a picture, you have to angles that add up to $90^\circ$ ($\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians).
[image]

- Where in the picture is $\arcsin(1-x)$?
- Where in the picture is $\arccos(\frac{1}{3})$?
- Can you find a relationship between the two?

---

(*Edit*)

*Since OP has already accepted an answer, I'll add some more details. $\arcsin(1-x)$ and $\arccos(\frac{1}{3})$ are just two angles that add up to $90^\circ$, and it doesn't matter which angle is which in the picture.*

[image]

*Geogebra won't let me write in LaTeX, so let $$\alpha=\arcsin(1-x)$$ $$\beta=\arccos(\frac{1}{3})$$ Then from the figure we see that $\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}$ is the $\color{red}{red}$ line, and $\color{green}{1-x}$ is the $\color{green}{green}$ line. These are equal in length, so you have to solve $$1-x=\frac{1}{3}$$ I'll leave the rest to you!*

Notice that this proves a more general result:

> Let $\alpha+\beta=90^\circ$, then $\sin(\alpha)=\cos(\beta)$, $\sin(\beta)=\cos(\alpha)$.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more than once ~

Comment: I couldn't find where they are.

Comment: @Cargobob Ok, I'll try to help you some more. When looking at $\arcsin(1-x)$ and $1-x$, which of the two is a length, and which of the two is an angle?

Comment: @DanielV Divines' bless your kind heart!

Comment: What a great answer this is!

Comment: @Cargobob Thank you for noticing $\sin(\pi)$!

Answer (score 1):

$$1-x=\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\arccos\frac13\right).$$

This can be further simplified.

Comment: How did you find that? Perhaps there would be an identitiy.

Comment: @Cargobob ! It comes from the definition of $sin$ and $arcsin$. They are reversed functions, for example, $sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$ and $arcsin(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

By using the identity

$$\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)~=~\frac{\pi}2 $$

The equation becomes

$$\begin{align}
\arcsin(1-x)+\left[\frac{\pi}2-\arcsin\left(\frac13\right)\right]~&=~\frac{\pi}2\\
\arcsin(1-x)~&=~\arcsin\left(\frac13\right)\\
1-x~&=~\frac13
\end{align}$$

and therefore you get $x=\frac23$.

---

On the other side you will get

$$\begin{align} 
\sin(1-x)+\cos\left(\frac13\right)~=~\frac{\pi}2\\
\sin(1-x)~=~\frac{\pi}2-\cos\left(\frac13\right)\\
1-x~=~\arcsin\left(\frac{\pi}2-\cos\left(\frac13\right)\right)\\
x~=~1-\arcsin\left(\frac{\pi}2-\cos\left(\frac13\right)\right)\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $\cos$ of both sides, expand and then use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Inverse_trigonometric_functions, solve the quadratic to get $x=1\pm1/3$, from which only $2/3$ qualifies as a real solution.